# How to save an interactive plot?

Tags: python, dataframe, ipywidgets

I'm creating an interactive plot using Pywedge Bibliothek in jupyter notebook using this code

```
x=pw.Pywedge_Charts(df, c=None, y='Number_Trips')
charts=x.make_charts()
charts
```

an example of the output is as follows [image: trips per days]

and i can desactivate as well as activate the day i want to see.. my question is how can i save it and keep it interactive to use it in a website or if it is even possible?

Comment: Why you have to use python in order to make interactive maps when u need to use on website...there are multiple ways we can create beautiful & much more interactive graphs directly on website itself...Like we can use Java Script, Chart.js...It is mandatory to use python here?...If u want to use python you can use flask & render image graph on html

Comment: @Bhargav Thank you dor ur suggestion , i've used plotly as in this website https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/ and it works as i really wanted .. thnx again :D

Answer (score 0):

The way to save interactivity is to save the source of `df` and the code to generate the plot. To open an interactive plot, run the script that generates it.

Comment: the problem is i want to share the plot in a website! and it doesn't make sense to share all the script.. :/

Comment: @Hermion. If you're sharing on a website, consider using a PNG or SVG or so. If you want an interactive plot, it must be aware of the underlying data one way or another.